# how to use a single controller for multiple routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

how to assign a couple of controller and view to multiple route patterns in AngularJS?
for example I have a couple of view and controller:

```
{
  templateUrl: '/partial/single-item.html',
  controller: 'SingleItemController'
}
```

witch I want them for two routes:

```
/car/:id
/bike/:id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a route like : /:myRoute/:id
And test in the controller(or in a route regex) the value of myRoute for example

Comment: thanks. But I can't use it. I have too many routes. It makes the routing complicated.

Comment: Why do you need to assign all routes to only one controller in fact ?

Comment: not all routs. only these two routes. I just want to keep the cod DRY. if fact the example is the exact code I have.

Comment: I think you cant make it without repeat it in your configProvider (when('/car/:id', {
   templateUrl: 'partials/car.html',
   controller: 'Uniquecontroller'
  })  etc...)

Comment: thanks you. I finaly found a way to use this approach: /:type/:id